# How to connect MS SQL Database using jdbc in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to connect MS SQL database using JDBC in Android Studio 1.1.0. I am refering to [this](http://www.parallelcodes.com/connect-android-to-ms-sql-database-2/) site for connecting. Here is my code for connecting:

```
  import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
  import android.os.StrictMode;
  import android.util.Log;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionClass {
String ip = "IP_Address(for eg.192.168.5.60)";
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db = "Andro";
String un = "username";
String password = "pwd";
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(classs);
       /* ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + "/"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";*/

       ConnURL= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP_Address(for eg.192.168.5.60)/databaseName=Andro;user=username;password=pwd;";
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);


    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
  }
 }
```

Calling connectionClass.CONN() function like this:

```
   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
        else
        {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {
                    heading.setText("u"+con.toString());
                    String query = "select * from Usertbl where UserId='" + userid + "' and Password='" + password + "'";

                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    heading.setText("After statement");
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                   // heading.setText(rs.getString(1));
                    z = "under else block";
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        z = "Login successfull";
                        isSuccess=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        z = "Invalid Credentials";
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
               z = "Exceptions";
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
```

I just want to connect database with android studio. The error shows like this

[image: Error while connecting database]

Please suggest any solution or any hint to perform connectivity.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace as text. And the problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with connecting to a database (which btw you shouldn't do directly from an android phone, use a webservice as an intermediary). The error in the screenshot suggests you are improperly trying to modify what is displayed (ie: from the wrong thread).

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are trying to set the text value of a textview field from the Asynchronous task.
**Over here :  heading.setText("u"+con.toString());**
Just remove this and the error might be solved.
Also note that Asynchronous task cannot set the value of the activity component like EditText,Textview or even a button field.

Answer (score 0):

i had also been trying to connect ms sql database from android studio, succeeded last night using the given link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRF8NpoFteg

note that jtds-1.2.7 must be downloaded, latest versions might not work for real mobile (i was facing this problem for one week the database connected on emulator but not on real mobile).

further after including jtds-1.2.7 gradle build might give an error of instant run kindly uncheck instant run from file -> settings -> instant run -> uncheck enable instant run.

hope it hepls!!!